# wait queues vs semaphores in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

Why do we use wait queues in the linux kernel rather than use semaphores for synchronization ? What is the difference between using wait queues vs semaphores for synchronization ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A semaphore is a variable or abstract data type that provides a simple but useful abstraction for controlling access by multiple processes to a common resource in a parallel programming environment. (**[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29)**)

Now, a semaphore is more of a concept, rather than a specific implementation.

The linux **semaphore** data structure implementation **uses a wait-queue**. Without a wait queue, you wouldn't know which process demanded the resource first, which could lead to very large wait times for some. The wait-queue **ensures fairness**, and abates the **resource starvation** problem.

```
struct semaphore {
    int count; //+ve or -ve indicates resource free/busy state
    int waking; //number of waiting processes
    int lock ;  /* to make waking testing atomic */
    struct wait_queue *wait; //queued, to prevent starvation, ensure fairness
};
```

**[Reference](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/kernel.html)**

Comment: does that mean waitqueues can be implemented in place of semaphores? Also is there any instace when a waitqueue is preferred over semaphore?

Comment: @sanrioalvares Please re-read the answer. When you use wait-queues, to ensure no resource conflict, you have realized a semaphore (which is something that controls access to a common resource). Wait-queues are encompassed within semaphores.